# How can I use this.getSelectedItemId() in Android

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I start learning android just now with sample examples. I encountered one  problem.

```
public class ContactActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final String[] mContent = new String[]{
       ContactDbHelper._ID,ContactDbHelper.NAME,ContactDbHelper.PHONE
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         mCursor = managedQuery(ContactProvider.CONTENT_URI, mContent, null, null, null);
         mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, mCursor, 
             new String[]{ ContactDbHelper.NAME, ContactDbHelper.PHONE },
             new int[]{ R.id.name, R.id.phone } );
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("position: ", "" + position);
        Log.i("id", "" + id);
        setSelection(position);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        long id = this.getSelectedItemId();
        Log.i("id: ", "" + id);
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case IDM_ADD: { CallAddContactDialog(); } break;
            case IDM_EDIT: if(id > 0) { CallEditContactDialog(id); } 
                  else {
                        Toast.makeText(this,R.string.toast_notify,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } break;
             case IDM_DELETE: if (id > 0) { CallDeleteContactDialog(id); } else {
                       Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_notify, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } break;
        }               
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It has been written here - `this.getSelectedItemId()` , and the code returned [INVALID_ROW_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#INVALID_ROW_ID), I read its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemId%28%29), but I didn't find any way to resolve it. What do I need to add to resolve the problem ? What does this.getSelectedItemId() returned , in general? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

My xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:textSize="18sp"/>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: something you have to do with `MenuItem item` it seems

Comment: yes, here `MenuItem item` works normally

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich: Are you just trying to get the id of the menu item that the user selected, or are you trying to get something else?

Comment: @Cornholio: I need `id` of the selected item from listview

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich That's your problem - this method isn't for the listview, it's for the `Activity`'s menu.

Comment: if you are looking at listView item id which is present in your activity then try `onItemClicked`

Comment: @Cornholio: You are right, but here the problem is little bit differently, I will edit my question now

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich I see what you're trying to do, but I think in most or all use cases, no list item will be selected at this point.

Comment: @Cornholio: I am beginner, I don't know system's things, so I ask a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select an item in a listview `getSelectedItemId ()` returns the _id of the selected item or INVALID_ROW_ID if no item is selected.
You need to implement `OnItemClickListener` and in `onItemClick` call `setSelection(position)` then your code will work.

Comment: I don't know how to set the `_id` ?

Comment: your mCursor has a column _id. Each row has an associated _id beside the position, it is the primary key of the table you query.

Comment: if it was, why `this.getSelectedItemId` returned `INVALID_ROW_ID` ?

Comment: did not help, I wrote logger inside `onItemClick` , it didn't show logs

Comment: Did you have any button or image view in the list items. If you do then the onTtemClick does not respond unless you put some property in the xml. If not then try to set android:choiceMode="singleChoice" in your listview

Comment: I edited again my question, maybe the edits will be answer your quesstion

Comment: after setListAdapter put getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); to see if onItemClick get call.

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but it did not help too, I edited my question again

Comment: Did you click on any item in the list? If so what is the model of your device? Can you try on another device?

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**

You're using the wrong method; for a ListView, you need to set an `OnClickListener`. This method is for the activity's menu.

Use `item.getItemId()` instead. Here's an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.menu.do_stuff: {
                // Do stuff
            } case R.menu.do_stuff2: {
                // Do other stuff
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you know, I did example like this, but the problem is not with what You are talking

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich Then what's the issue? It almost sounds like you're trying to get the id of the selected `ListView` item, but there's never a `ListView` item selected when the user clicks on a menu item.

Comment: i wrote as in example, i have not changes